# Value from select on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is driving me crazy, I've looked at many different answers, posts and the jQuery examples and yet the simple JS that I have is not giving me the actual value, any help appreciated.

I'm trying to populate a menu options form depending on the number of adults / children.  In this case you'd select form a dropdown `#numberOfAdults`, the value is 2 and then 2 separate menu choices appear, hardly rocket science and yet...it's elusive.

My form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="numberOfAdults" id="numberOfAdults" tabindex="2">
        <option>-Adults-</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The JS: (this is the latest version, I've tried `this.value`, `id.val()`, and so on.

```
$('#numberOfAdults').change(function() {
     var val1 = this.value;
     var val2 = $('#numberOfAdults option:selected').val();

     alert(val1 + " - " + val2);
});
```

With the above I aways obtain 'Adults - Adults', I can never actually get value 1 or value 2 to show nd I'm sure it's something trivial that I've missed.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Replaced min with cdn and still the same result. 
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Azmin, my aim is to use the value obtained to show n number of menu selections.  if there is 1 adult then 1 menu selection, if 2 then 2 and so on,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is working as you want it to:

```js
$('#numberOfAdults').change(
  function() {
    var val1 = this.value;
    var val2 = $('#numberOfAdults option:selected').val();

    alert(val1 + " - " + val2);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <select name="numberOfAdults" id="numberOfAdults" tabindex="2">
    <option>-Adults-</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: gah! any idea why this might not be working in the environment that I have?

Comment: @SteveGreen what is you environment? ;) Can you link to the full project?

Comment: It's a 'simple' bloated bootstrap theme that I'm playing with, intellij as the IDE with Spring integration for when I finally get this bastard form working. :)

I can create a new repo and add the files or - I've just pastebinned the index page. http://pastebin.com/dgQHscvG

Comment: why did you copy paste exact code in you answer if it was working fine? it should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno why it happened to you. it might be there is something wrong with JQuery includes or mistypo. but it work perfectly when I post your code on snippet

```js
$('#numberOfAdults').change(function() {
    var val1 = this.value;
    var val2 = $('#numberOfAdults option:selected').val();

    alert(val1 + " - " + val2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="numberOfAdults" id="numberOfAdults" tabindex="2">
        <option>-Adults-</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using a local copy that minimised.  Will try with the cdn to see if that helps.

Comment: I suggest you to open your your tools to iterate process of jquery, e.g: firebug on mozilla. thus you can see the miss/bug you have.